# Define certain letter in math-mode to be always non-italic

Tags: math-mode, fonts, amsmath, italic

Imagine I have a 500 page book about complex numbers.

But I always wrote just `j` in math-mode as the **imaginary unit**. But I should have written `\mathrm{j}`. Is there a command I could write into my preamble to substitute all `j` with `\mathrm{j}`? It would be quite some pain in the ass, to do it for all **j** manually.
(There are no appearances of j as running index or other meanings)

For some greek letters where I have the same problem I used:

```
\let\Theta\varTheta
```

But I don't know how to do the same for "normal letters".

**Minimal example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
j ~~is not~~ \mathrm{j}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems similiar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845598/emacs-regex-replacing-a-string-inside-a-latex-equation) one. Can you use regular expression and `grep` for instance to solve your problem (without LaTeX)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathSymbol{j}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`j}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
j ~~is~~ \mathrm{j}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```