# Define certain letter in math-mode to be always non-italic - using unicode-math in lualatex

Tags: math-mode, fonts, amsmath, luatex, unicode-math

I once had [**this question**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194750/define-certain-letter-in-math-mode-to-be-always-non-italic) a while ago, asking about how to set the letter ***j*** always to be non-italic **j** in math mode without using `\mathrm`.

The provided solution was:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{j}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`j}
```

However, since I changed to **lualatex** and **unicode-math** the above line has either

### no effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}          
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareMathSymbol{j}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`j}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
j ~~\text{is not}~~ \mathrm{j}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or in case I define e.g. MinionPro and MnSymbol as my math fonts, the **j**

### disappears completely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}          
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont{MnSymbol}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-It}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-BoldIt}
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,StylisticSet={1}]{XITS Math}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}

\DeclareMathSymbol{j}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`j}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
j ~~\text{is not}~~ \mathrm{j}
\end{equation}
But actually $j$ is not there at all.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried to declare the unicode character **j** separately, which didn't worked out.

```
\setmathfont[range={"006A} ]{Minion Pro}
```

It made appear the **j** again, but it was still italic.

---

**Any new solutions for the old problem in case unicode-math is used?**

I hope it was the appropriate action to ask a new question. I didn't wanted to alter the old question as it would have made the answer invalid.

---

### Edit:

Not knowing that it would be important, I also need to include the **amssymb** package, which together with [egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239767/36835) gives the following result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}            
    
\usepackage{fontspec}          
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont{MnSymbol}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-It}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-BoldIt}
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,StylisticSet={1}]{XITS Math}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}

\AfterEndPreamble{ %
\Umathcode`j="0"4"6A
}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
j ~~\text{is not}~~ \mathrm{j}
\end{equation}
But actually $j$ is not there at all.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}          
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\AtBeginDocument{\Umathcode`j="0"0"6A }

\begin{document}




\begin{equation}
j ~~\text{is}~~ \mathrm{j}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I don't have MinionPro. but here is your extended version using Arial (you want 6)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}            

\usepackage{fontspec}          
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmathfont{MnSymbol}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Arial}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Arial}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Arial}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Arial}
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,StylisticSet={1}]{XITS Math}
\setmathrm{Arial}

\AfterEndPreamble{ %
\Umathcode`j="0"6"6A
}


\begin{document}
\showoutput
\begin{equation}
j ~~\text{is}~~ \mathrm{j}
\end{equation}
But actually $j$ is not there at all.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does solve the problem for the standard font in the first MWE, it does not work for the second MWE.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I didn't do that one as I don't have the font but I just fixed your extended example using a substituted font, see updated answer

Comment: it finally was `\Umathcode`j="0"10"6A`  - and I'd say the most robust way is to put these command directly after the `\setmathrm` command. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the proper family number for `j`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont{MnSymbol}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Minion Pro} % this is number 4
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-It}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-BoldIt}
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,StylisticSet={1}]{XITS Math}

\AtBeginDocument{\Umathcode`j="0"4"6A }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
j \text{ is } \mathrm{j}\ne\mathbf{j}\ne\mathit{j}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The use of the **amssymb** package seems to invalidate your soluton (see my edit) - can you tell why and how to fix that? And where did you got the *"0"4"6A* from. I always find *006A* for **j**. I'm sorry that I haven't included this information in the first place, it didn't seemed relevant.

Comment: @thewaywewalk he got it from my answer of course:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found *006A* in the unicode table and suggested it in my question. You gave me the right code to make it work for the default font, but then egreg suggested to use *046A* instead, which worked also for this case. But now with amssymb loaded it seems to change again. I'm very confused where all the character mappings come from.

Comment: @thewaywewalk ignore the banter between egreg and me:-) LaTeX dynamically allocates math fonts and hides the font allocation numbers behind symbolic names such as `letters` but unicode-math isn't quite expecting you to do this so you need to see what number has been allocated to the `mathrm` font and use the same number in the primitive `\Umathcode` so it could be 0 or 4 or 6 or any other number between 0 and 255 (or 15) depending on  the order in which you declare fonts in the preamble.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I added  `\showoutput
\begin{equation}
j ~~\text{is}~~ \mathrm{j}\showlists
\end{equation}`  and the log showed `.\fam6 j` so I needed 6 which is `"6` in hex.